# Problems saving Office Files to shared drives

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel

I can connect to the network drive with no problems, open files and work on them. However when in office programs, when I go to save files, I'm getting the error message below. If I save them with a different file name, then I'm able to save them. Does anyone know what the cause may be?

Screenshot - looks like belongs from XP!
[image: Screenshot - looks like belongs from XP!]

Answer (score 0):

The naming of office files is regular, do not use special symbols such as:?! (), do not use characters that are too long, and do not name conflicts with other file names.

Answer (score 0):

This very probably relates to the permissions you have over the network share.

Saving under the same name implies being able to delete the old version.
If the delete is impossible, then the workaround is to save under
another name.

You should examine the permissions you have on the share, by right-click
in Explorer of the share and select Properties, in the Security tab.

(As you advance in the analysis, take screenshots and add them into
your post when necessary.)